# When implementing IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode(T obj), can I use the current instance's state, or do I have to use obj?

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism

How come when I implement IEqualityComparer, it has a parameter for GetHashCode(T obj)?  It's not a static object of course, so why can't I just use the current instance's state to generate the hash code?  Is `this == obj`?

I'm curious because I'm trying to do this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass : IEqualityComparer<BaseClass>
{
    public abstract int GetHashCode(BaseClass obj);
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int MyData;

    public override int GetHashCode(BaseClass obj)
    {
        return MyData.GetHashCode();
        // Or do I have to do this:
        // return (DerivedClass)obj.MyData.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to prevent doing the cast, since it's being used in really high-performance code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that you're confusing [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx).

**`IEquatable<T>`** defines a method for determining if the current instance (`this`) is equal to an instance of the same type. In other words it's used for testing `objA.Equals(objB)`. When implementing this interface, it is recommended that you also override the `GetHashCode()` instance method.

**`IEqualityComparer<T>`** defines methods for testing whether two objects of the given type are equal, in other words, it's for testing `comparer.Equals(objA, objB)`. Hence the necessity to to provide an object as a parameter to `GetHashCode` (which, remember is different than the `GetHashCode` that it inherits from `object`)

You can think of `IEquatable<T>` as your object's way of saying, "*this is how I know if I am equal to something else,*" and `IEqualityComparer<T>` as your object's way of saying, "*this is how I know if two other things are equal*".

For some good examples of how these two interfaces are used in the framework see:

- [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements `IEquatable<string>`
- [`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements `IEqualityComparer<string>`

Should you use the current state of an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to determine the hash code? If the state is at all mutable, then **no!** Anywhere where the hash is used (e.g. `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<T, V>`) the hash code will be cached and used for efficient lookup. If that hash code can change because the state of the comparer changes, that would totally destroy the usefulness of the data structure storing the hash. Now, if the state is not mutable (i.e. it's set only when creating the comparer and cannot be modified throughout the lifetime of the comparer), then yes, you can, but I would still recommend against it, unless you have a really good reason.

Finally, you mentioned performance. Honestly, this sounds like [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). I'd recommend not worrying so much about performance until you can be sure that this particular line of code is causing a problem.

Comment: When will object.GetHashCode() get called, and when will IEquatable<T>.GetHashCode() be called?

Also, the state only is set when creating the instance.  I'm basically trying to make my class as much like a value type as I can.

Comment: `GetHashCode()` (from either interface) is called when you need to quickly compare two objects or to store the object in a `HashSet<T>` (because it later uses the hash for quick comparisons). The difference is that `object.GetHashCode()` returns a hash for the current object, while `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode(T)` returns a hash for a given object.

Comment: So if I'm putting these in a HashSet<BaseClass>, what should I do to make sure only instances with unique type and state are added?  If I have two DerivedClass instances with the same MyData, only one should get added.

Comment: The most basic rule is, **if two objects are equal, then they must have the same hash code** (two objects that are not equal *may* have the same hash code, too). Beyond that, you can implement it any way you like—although implementing a *good* hash function is a lot more difficult and depends a lot on the design and intended use of your type. This applies whether your implementing `IEquatable<T>` or `IEqualityComparer<T>`. And again, I wouldn't focus on it until you're sure that this is a performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using information from passed in `obj` arguments your hash code will not vary for different incoming objects and will not be useful. Comparer *is not* instance of object you want to get hash code for or compare to.

Indeed you can use local fields of comaprer in `GetHashCode` and even can return `MyData` as hash code as shown in your sample - it will still satisfy `GetHashCode` requirement to "return the same value data for the same object". But in your sample all hash codes will be the same for instance of comparer and hence using it for `Dictionary` will essentially turn dictionary into list.

The same applies to `Equals` call - indeed you can return `true` all the time, but how useful it will be?

Comment: Well in my case, I want the equality to behave like structs do: different instances with the same state should be equal.  The reason why I don't just use structs is because I need some polymorphism stuff.

Comment: @terence - p.s.w.g. have very nice answer (+1 indeed) that hopefully clarify things. Another way to look at `IEqualityComparer` is to think about it as 2 static helper functions - with such mindset it may be more obvious that you must use information from incoming object.